# How export clean SVG file on Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

There is always a layer named Group> with my exported asset 
How to get rid of it?

[image: WINDOW]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the round dot on the right of your layers panel, this will cause illustrator to select the group*. You can now hit delete.

*Thats right  hilighting  a item does not select it. The dot does.

Oh and PS: They  arent layers only  to top  item is actually a layer. Its just misnamed due to historical reasons.

Answer (score -3):

activities are:

Activity 1-- Open Adobe Illustrator by double-clicking the program sign on the computer system's desktop computer.

Action 2-- Select the "File" as well as "Open" food choice switches and open the JPG picture on your computer system to change to vector format.

Activity 3-- Select the "Objects" food selection option and additionally find the "Real-time Trace" food selection alternative. This feature will definitely aid you to generate a vector mapping of the source photo to enable it to be rescaled appropriately.

Idea 4-- Select the desired setups for the Live Trace. For a basic trace, the default alternatives will certainly suffice while photos with a better degree of detail will certainly require you to modify the prepping to "Image-- High Stability."

Pointer 5-- Repeat the treatment as needed achieving the desired picture excellent quality. The Live Vector trace will certainly transform based upon the selections picked. As quickly as completely satisfied with the picture look close to the "Configuration Home window."

Action 6-- Conserve the brand-new vector documents on your computer in the desired vector documents kind to end up the conversion from JPG.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, this does not answer the question.

Comment: Hi @mariablassingame and welcome to GDSE! It seems to me like your answer is helpful but difficult to decypher in English. You can [edit it](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/125233/edit) to avoid further downvotes